# Unable to turn on Autocomplete On

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've this [page](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/enquiry/PNR/PnrEnquiry.html?locale=en) and there is an input text element(Enter PNR No):

```
<input class="form-control_custom input_text_custom" type="text" id="inputPnrNo" maxlength="10" value="" placeholder="Enter PNR No." onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 48 &amp;&amp; event.charCode <= 57) ||  event.charCode == 0)" >
```

I've added `autocomplete` as in below:

```
<input class="form-control_custom input_text_custom" type="text" id="inputPnrNo" maxlength="10" value="" placeholder="Enter PNR No." onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 48 &amp;&amp; event.charCode <= 57) ||  event.charCode == 0)" autocomplete="on">
```

But autocomplete is not turning on. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you add `autocomplete="on"` in your `form` tag?

Comment: @elegant-user Yes I've you can see in the code snippet

Comment: There is no `<form` tag in code you shared.